Can you render the calendar view first then the time view in MUI DatetimePicker?
I have upgraded the @mui/x-date-pickers from V5 to V7. The default behaviour of the DatetimePicker component is that it will render the calendar view first to select year, month and day and then it will render a clock. You can see it here in this demo (V5) from the docs.
However in the latest version that is not the default behaviour and there doesn't seem to be a happy path to achieve this with the component's API. See it in this demo (V7).
I have tried to change the views prop of the component manually but I would need a prop like onDayChange which isn't available unlike onMonthChange and onYearChange
However I've tried to store the views in state and change them when the month changes to see if it would work. You can see in the second demo. So I would need something like what I've done with the onMonthChange Is there something I am missing to achieve this?
